# Algorithm to determine if a word could be English?

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I have a list of strings that I need to check against an English dictionary.
However I don't want to start checking every piece of gibberish in the list. First, I want to check if the string could be an English word.

Does anyone know of an algorithm that does this or at least the rules that I need to apply to verify a word?

For example:

No spoken word can start with more than 3 consonants, and if there are are 3 initial consonants in a word, the first one must be "s".

Comment: What about 'through'?  That violates both of your examples.  There is probably far too much variation in English to be able to find a general rule to categorize.

Comment: Psst, don't tell anyone but that rule isn't always true. :)

Comment: The example is a bit CRYPTic. As you can see, CRYPT starts with even 5 consonants without the first being an "s" :-)

Comment: Use a suitable index to search stuff quickly and don't bother trying to second-guess what could and what couldn't be a word...

Comment: Besides, even if you find a rule that does work universally, how selective will it be? And how much will it cost to evaluate the rule for every single word? If most of your words are expected to be English, it's definitely not worth it.

Comment: The problem you've got is that there are no rules. Your examples are contradictory - no words start with 3 constants, words that start with three constants must start with an 's' - xylophone, ptyxis, hybrid, christmas

Comment: Any rules based on the initial characters of the word can in any case be caught perfectly well sticking the dictionary in a trie (or partial trie based on the first few letters). Then you don't have to guess - if it were true that no English word starts with four consonants, then a four-level trie would "know" that. But unless there are some peculiar constraints, just stick the whole dictionary in memory in a structure with reasonably fast lookup (tree, hashtable, whatever your language provides under the name "set"), and check every piece of gibberish.

Comment: I was about to say that there is no rule in English, but realized that's an oxymoron.

Comment: But perhaps a heuristic is possible instead of an algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding a word in a data structure is going to be fast (e.g. use a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (mind the false positives!), or a set)  so chances are it is not worth doing this for efficiency reasons.

If you want to provide suggestions, then look at Peter Norvig's [spell checking](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)  implementation.

If you really want to go that way, then I'd construct frequencies of A follows B from existing text to see whether any given sequence is contained within English words.

Comment: Why would you conduct a binary search of a list, instead of using a constant-time structure?

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate the point (probably badly).  I'll edit the wording.  Also you're going to get false positives with a Bloom filter (that's the trade off).

Comment: Bloom filter might also be useful if the dictionary doesn't fit in memory, so that access to it is much slower than access to the filter. The filter does have false positives, but all positives can be checked against the slower, more accurate dictionary. This can be a big saving if most of the input is negatives, although that's on some tenuous assumptions - (1) the dictionary doesn't fit in memory in a hashtable, which would be straight better than a Bloom filter, (2) enough of the text is non-English that the saving is worth it.

Comment: Yup, we've gone off at a tangent though!  The point I was trying to make is that it's incredibly quick to check a dictionary (with whatever structure you use).  Prechecking the word against some rules (for the reasons of speed) is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of task is what computers are for. Use some kind of set structure (maybe a bloom filter) to store all the words in a dictionary, and just check your word against it. That's a constant time operation.